# How can I unescape / urldecode query URL query variables in perl?

Tags: perl, escaping, cgi

I have a perl script that processes URLs - it was working fine until the server got upgraded. Now it seems to be double encoding the URL string that it returns.

Here is an example of the URL the script used to return:

```
https://processor.com/?&streetOne=johndoe%40test%2Ecom&key=1234
```

and here is what it is returning now

```
https://processor.com/?&email=johndoe%2540test%252Ecom&key=1234
```

They key difference is that the `@` in the URL used to be encoded correctly as `%40` but now the percent sign is getting encoded (double encoding) so it is `%2540` which is what happens if you encode the `@` and then encode it again.

I'm not sure what would have changed on the server to cause this behavior. I'm a PHP guy and it reminds me of the "magic quotes" where it would auto-escape all of the query variables to received before the script processed it.

I don't have root access to this server, so if it is not possible to make a change with an `.htaccess` file or some local configuration option (in the perl script?) then I might need to change what is happening in this function, which gets each of the URL values requested:

#### First the script reads the Query Variables

(I think this is where the problem could be - I don't understand the regex - something about looking for KEY between white space, and what the `$obj->{'key'};` part is doing)

```
sub getValue
{
  my $obj = shift;
  my $name = shift;

  if ($name =~ /^\s*KEY\s*$/i)
    {
      return $obj->{'key'};
    }

  if (! $obj->isValid($name))
    {
      $obj->addError("Cannot obtain information for field '$name' since field is invalid");
      return 0;
    }

  if (! $obj->isAssigned($name))
    {
      $obj->addError("Cannot obtain value from field '$name' since field has not be assigned a value.");
      return 0;
    }

  return $obj->{'parameters'}->{ $name }->{ 'value'};
}
```

#### Then script builds the query variables back into a URL to return:

There is another part of the script that builds the URL that it returns - but I don't think this is the culprit. I tried removing the `CGI::escape` from the `CGI::escape($value))` part and it did not help.

```
sub create_results
{
  my $obj = shift;

  my ($seconds, $microseconds) = gettimeofday();
  my $timestamp = int($seconds*1000 + $microseconds/1000);

  $obj->assign('timestamp',$timestamp);

  # create query string and hash data

  my $hash_data = '';

  my @query_string = qw();

  foreach my $name (@{ $obj->{'parameter_order'} })
    {
      my $node = $obj->{'parameters'}->{ $name };

      if (defined($node->{'value'}))
        {
          my $value = $node->{'value'};
          $hash_data .= $value;

          # $query->param(-name=>"$name",   -value=>"$value");
          push(@query_string,$name . "=" . CGI::escape($value));
        }
    }

  # Hash
  $hash_data .= $obj->get('key');
  my $hash_digest = md5_hex( $hash_data );

  push(@query_string, "hash=$hash_digest");

  $obj->{'query_string'} = join("&",@query_string);
  $obj->{'hash_digest'} = $hash_digest; 
}
```

The script is a perl package that I'm using. I didn't write it. I posted the full script here: http://pastebin.com/eZr8rQ0t

Comment: This is an awful question. You should be able to demonstrate this problem with 5 lines of code, but you didn't demonstrate the problem at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the CGI module is a bit dated, and `CGI::escape` is an undocumented, internal function inside `CGI::Util`, which is meant for CGI internals *only*. There is a corresponding `unescape` function available, but this is hardly *The Right Thing* to do.

To cut the chase short, using `CGI::Util::unescape($dirty_value)` somewhere should work, as that module should aready be loaded by `CGI`. Maybe at the `return` from `getValue`, but I am to tired to find the correct place. This double-encoding seems like a design error, or the example URL you gave is assumed to be escaped already, and the script is just used wrong.

I'd bet on wrong design; considering that somebody thought it was fun to do

```
"foo" => { "parameterName" => "foo" },
... # snip like 50 other values
"quux" => { "parameterName" => "quux" },
```

and other dumbness where `map { $_ => {parameterName => $_} } qw/foo ... qux/` would have worked with a fraction of typing …

**Hint:** Documentation for all (public) Perl modules (incl. source code) is available at https://metacpan.org/.

Comment: Oh dear Lord … manual generation of setters and getters \*look of shock and disbelief\* it isn't Perl if it isn't lazy.

Comment: Here is an updated version with all the unneccessary repetition factored out: http://pastebin.com/9DqCn9Qs This should make reading the code a bit easier. It even compiles. (also, filesize: now a third LOC of the original)